# How does 0+= VARIABLE result in VARIABLE+1?

Tags: c, operators, increment

I ran into a strange bug when updating a counter that is used to calculate the variable for a switch statement.

`int iCount` was assigned zero outside of the loop, and it is the counter used for the while loop.

To update the counter inside the loop, I wrote `iCount+= packedCount`, where packedCount was 7 in this case.  In the debugger, however, 0+=packedCount resulted in packedCount+1, which was 8.  That resulted in an array slot remaining unfilled throughout the loop.

When I changed the line to `icount= packedCount+iCount`, the proper value was returned.

So, is this behavior unique to C, as I do this regularly in Java with no strange effects.

**EDIT**- Code snippet added

```
#define SKIP   8
#define PACKED 7

int iCount;
iCount=0;

while (iCount < characters-1){  
    for (packedCount=iCount; packedCount< iCount+PACKED; packedCount++){ 
        //ASCII compressor logic goes here
    }
    //iCount+= packedCount; //this produces 8 for 0+packedCount

    //this works
    iCount= iCount+packedCount; //skip the next byte in array, since it was already packed
}
```

Comment: what about posting some code?

Comment: Probably some corruption or something -- post the code.

Comment: is that a typo? **icount** = packedCount+iCount; <- all lowercase icount on the left of the equals sign?

Comment: Please post the complete code of the loop that causes this error.

Comment: I am surprised nobody has asked you to post your code yet.

Comment: @BlackBear, et al, code posted.  @Jon Reid, compiler is gcc 4.4.5 in Ubuntu Maverick

Answer (score 3):

As far as the compilers are concerned

```
iCount += packedCount;
iCount = iCount + packedCount;
```

are identical. If they're producing different results, then something in your code is causing iCount to get trashed - a bad pointer reference, perhaps.

Comment: I've been running into those problems alot on this project.  The joys of learning a new language and paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and other variations you can think of:

```
#define SKIP   8
#define PACKED 7

int iCount;
iCount=0;

while (iCount < characters-1){  
    for (packedCount=iCount; packedCount< iCount+PACKED; packedCount++){ 
        //ASCII compressor logic goes here
    }
    printf("iCount after the inner loop: %d\n", iCount);             /* DEBUG */
    printf("packedCount after the inner loop: %d\n", packedCount);   /* DEBUG */

    //iCount+= packedCount; //this produces 8 for 0+packedCount

    //this works
    iCount= iCount+packedCount; //skip the next byte in array, since it was already packed

    printf("iCount after update: %d\n", iCount);                     /* DEBUG */
}
```

Comment: Adding that debug code is unneccessary in my view, since those values popped right up in ddd.  If I didn't have the debugger, then your suggestion would be valid.